# InfluxDB field values mixed from another measurement

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, influxdb, measurement, influxdb-python

I'm sending data into **influx-DB 1.8 OSS**, which has 2 measurements. In that one measurement got mixed field values from another measurement.

Eg:

measurement 1

`field: Apple, Banana, Grapes, Orange`

Measurement 2

`field: Potato, Cucumber, Onion, Carrot`

When I checked **measurement 1**, I got the result:

`Apple Banana Potato Grapes Onion Orange.`

Why did this happen? I'm using ***Python*** to push data to InfluxDB. For **measurement 1** and **measurement 2** I'm using separate function. And using **Multiprocessing** to Push at the same time to InfluxDB.

Please suggest why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I have no right to add comment right now so post suggestions here.

Could you try share your JSON body for your Python client so that we could nail down the root cause? I might just double check the measurement section in the JSON body. There is a great [example](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/getting-started-python-influxdb/) you could try on. In your case, the body could be:

```
>>> json_body = 
    [
        {
            "measurement": "measurement 1",
            "time": "2018-03-28T8:01:00Z",
            "fields": {
                "Apple": 11,
                "Banana": 12,
                "Grapes": 13,
                "Orange": 14
            }
        },
        {
            "measurement": "measurement 2",
            "time": "2018-03-28T8:02:00Z",
            "fields": {
                "Potato": 21,
                "Cucumber": 22,
                "Onion": 23,
                "Carrot": 24
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Yes, the JSON body is the same as yours. as the values for the field values are dynamic my JSON body goes through for loop. and the body is like

```
list = []
for i in function():
   JSONBODY = {
            "measurement": "measurement 1",
            "time": "2018-03-28T8:01:00Z",
            "fields": {
                "Apple": 11,
                "Banana": 12,
                "Grapes": 13,
                "Orange": 14
            }
        }
list.append(JSONBODY)

```

Comment: Cool then. You may try to print out or log the each JSONBODY and try to see whether the measurement sections are misplaced.

Comment: Actually I will append these lists into a CSV file and push this into the InfluxDB later. And when I checked the CSV file, I didn't find any mistakes. Is it because of the internet slowness? I don't know it's just my assumption.

Comment: That's odd. No matter the quality of internet, data of measurement 1 won't mix up with that of measurement 2. I am curious of the content of the CSV file. Maybe one more peek on the measurement sections.

Comment: The CSV file looks like this:
```

"measurement","tags","fields","time"
"measurement1","{Tag1 : tag, Tag2 : tag2 }","{"Apple": 11, "Banana": 12,"Grapes": 13, "Orange": 14}",1653029005621
"measurement2","{Tag1 : tag, Tag2 : tag2 }","{"Potato": 11, "Cucumber": 12,"Onion": 13, "Carrot": 14}",1653029005622
"measurement1","{Tag1 : tag, Tag2 : tag2 }","{"Apple": 11, "Banana": 12,"Grapes": 13, "Orange": 14}",1653029005623
"measurement2","{Tag1 : tag, Tag2 : tag2 }","{"Potato": 11, "Cucumber": 12,"Onion": 13, "Carrot": 14}",1653029005624

```

Comment: Also, I have two functions. where one function handles this CSV file and another function handles the same like another CSV file. Is it because of that?

Comment: The CSV content look good to me so far. It has one row indicating the annotation and the rest of four rows are the data: four records into two measurement. We might look at the Python parser you wrote and make sure it can read the CSV in the right way. You may print out the intermediate JSON python as a log when the parser is reading the CSV. Or you may try using v1.8's Flux. It can read CSV with some format much easily: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/reference/syntax/annotated-csv/